# ngdata table filter ui is not visible

Tags: primeng

I am using primeng datatable which is awesome but had a problem on multiselect filter. I checked data with chrome inspect and I have right select box but it is not visible..

My code is below also..

```
<p-column field="companyId" header="companyId" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="in">
    <ng-template let-person="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        {{getOrganizationNameFromId(person.companyId)}}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter">
        <p-multiSelect [options]="orgSelectItems"
                       defaultLabel="All Users"
                       styleClass="ui-column-filter"
                       (onChange)="filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)"
        ></p-multiSelect>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

[image: problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `appendTo="body"` to your multiselect !

```
<p-column field="companyId" header="companyId" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="in">
        <ng-template let-person="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            {{getOrganizationNameFromId(person.companyId)}}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="filter">
            <p-multiSelect [options]="orgSelectItems"
                           appendTo="body"
                           defaultLabel="All Users"
                           styleClass="ui-column-filter"
                           (onChange)="filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)"
            ></p-multiSelect>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: It seems to solve the problem. But it also change the style of the multiselect. Can you point to the doc for appendTo?